# How do I print only the date from this line using Python in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<td colspan="6" style="background-color: #fff;text-align: center;font-weight:bold;">Draw Date:  2019-01-15</td>
```

How do I print only the `2019-01-15` part? This value is stored in the `date` variable.

Comment: `date.string` and then `split()` and indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date.string.split()[-1]
#'2019-01-15'
```